# Cast to a pointer to a private class function

Tags: c++

I have a callback that is defined around the following:

```
namespace {

bool OnEvent(int16_t* buffer, size_t num_samples, void* ptr_to_class) {
  return reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(ptr_to_class)->EventHandler(buffer, num_samples);
}

} // anonymous namespace
```

But, to be able to call the `EventHandler()` inside this callback, I had to define it as public. I was wondering if there's a way to define it as a private member and in the callback, pass the pointer to this private function instead?

Something like

```
namespace {

bool OnEvent(int16_t* buffer, size_t num_samples, void* ptr_to_function) {
  return reinterpret_cast<MyClass::EventHandler*>(ptr_to_function)(buffer, num_samples);
}

} // anonymous namespace
```

which doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to have an object of the class type in order to call a member function of it unless it is a static function.

Comment: You can't break the private thing. It isn't like a const. The best you can do is using `friend`

Comment: It is possible to use an std::function+lambda function, but not sure if this is really any different from making the EventHandler public.
e.g.
std::function<bool(int16_t* buffer, size_t num_samples> getHandler() {
     return [=](int16_t* b, size_t num) { return EventHandler(b, num); };
}

Comment: Please also show how the callback is registered / set up to be called later.  Is the code which registers and invokes the callback C++ code under your control, or is it an external library or needs a C interface?

Comment: Usually if your function is private, then you should only call that function from inside the class itself. Also if you want to call a member function via a pointer, then your syntax is wrong. It should look like `(ptr_to_object->*ptr_to_member)(args)`. Casting do not works well in that case as you need to understand many internal details to make it works. Here are some information: https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c17401/C-Tutorial-PointertoMember-Function.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::bind to give access to private functions:

```
class PFunctor{
    int m_value=0;

    int getValue(){
        return m_value;
    }
    void setValue(int val){
        m_value = val;
    }

public:

    std::function<int()> getPFunc(){
        return std::bind(&PFunctor::getValue,this);
    }
    auto setPFunc(){
        return std::bind(&PFunctor::setValue,this, std::placeholders::_1);
    }
};

...

PFunctor tfunctor;
auto getfunc = tfunctor.getPFunc();
auto setfunc = tfunctor.setPFunc();
std::cout << getfunc() << std::endl;
setfunc(-100);
std::cout << getfunc() << std::endl;
```

I included both explicit std::function use and auto use.